# MapViewBalloons project. Implement Pushpin changes color when Tapped

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a Library called [MapViewBalloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons). I would like to change the color of my pushpin once the user taps in the Pushpin.

I had been trying different strategies and not able to implement the same.
The general question would be how to **change an overlay** item when a click has been done in it.

I hope someone who has used this library can answer this question.